# How to properly create symbolic link?

Tags: linux, bash, symbolic-link

scenario :

1. I'm in a place that is not in PATH
2. I have a file name `dofoo` that is executable
3. I want to create symbolic link in `/usr/bin` that points to `dofoo` in current directory

quite hard to get the basics. I can do with

```
$ cd /usr/bin
$ sudo ln -s /previous/path/dofoo
$ cd /previous/path
```

but I'd like to be this done with single command.
here's what I have tried(assuming I'm in /previous/path):

```
$ sudo ln -s dofoo /usr/bin/dofoo
$ /usr/bin/dofoo
bash: /usr/bin/dofoo: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command should look like

```
sudo ln -s $PWD/dofoo /usr/bin
```

This will produce the expected result. The manpage is a bit unclear about TARGET (at least to me).

Comment: +1. the content of a symbolic link is the path to the target file, so always provide the absolute or relative path, not just the program name.

Comment: Fantastic answer! This is useful in soooo many places and I've spent hours dealing with the consequences of not knowing this. Just shows, if you ask the right questions... Thanks