# Symlink that runs a script when accessed (Linux)

Tags: linux, script, symbolic-link, bash-scripting

I would like to make a symbolic link that refers to a file *and* runs a script every time it is accessed (specifically one that shows a notification and logs to a file). After a quick search of Google and various Stack Exchanges, I am no closer to an answer. What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly create symbolic link?](https://superuser.com/questions/601047/how-to-properly-create-symbolic-link)

Comment: You need at least two parts, and probably a 3rd. Either a watcher programs that records runs and accesses, or a 3rd item that both starts the logging AND calls the symlink. Either way, you need to do some more research I think.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a symlink with `ln -s /target/script /link/path`.

Then set the default application for the script to your default shell, e.g. `/bin/bash`. How you do that depends on your desktop environment.

For example on KDE, you would right-click the script, select `open with -> other application`

[image]

Then check the box at `remember application association`, enter `/bin/bash` in the input field and click `OK`.

[image]

To test if it works, you can create a script with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
logger "symlink works"
```

Then watch the output of your syslog with `journalctl -f` for the line `username[id] symlink works`

Comment: This just makes a symlink to a script. I need a link to a file that also runs the script.

Comment: @BenjaminKorpella You cannot create a symbolic link which points to two files.

Comment: Any explanation for the downvote?